# using getElementById to style a div's paragaph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, on the hover of an image, I want the paragraph in that div to disappear. So, I am trying to do something like this:

```
$("#One1 img").hover(function(){
    var par = document.getElementById('One1 p');
   par.style.display = "none";
},function(){});
```

but I get the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null'

I know to getElementById for a div is just `var par = document.getElementById('One1');` but how can I get the paragraph inside of that div? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` will only fetch element with said id, it won't take any css selector as its argument.

Since you are using jQuery, just use the selectors provided by it

```
$("#One1 img").hover(function () {
    $('#One1 p').hide();
}, function () {
    $('#One1 p').show();
});
```

- [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)
- [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `document.getElementById('One1 p');` put `document.querySelector("#One1 p")`, because `document.getElementById` gets the id of an element, and selectors don't work like putting a space and then a `p`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with jQuery:

```
$("#One1 img").hover(function(){
    $("#One p").css("display", "none");
},function(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have JQuery so why aren't you using it to do this?

```
$('#One1 img').hover(function(){
    // get the parent element (#One1) with .parent()
    // and hide all p elements in it
    $(this).parent().find('p').hide();
});
```

This solution is more flexible, #One1 can also be a class which appears multiple times on the page with this solution.